# Advice with ArrayAdpters

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me what exactly does an array adapter do? I've tried searching the net but all I get is code examples. Please explain me what it does, I've visited the android developers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `ArrayAdapter` can be used as a data source for a number of different Android Views, such as a `ListView` or a `Spinner`.

Basically, you pass some kind of array or list to the constructor of an `ArrayAdapter`. Then, the adapter can be hooked up to a `ListView` by calling [setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter%28android.widget.ListAdapter%29).  You can also use the `add` and `remove` methods of the adapter to modify the underlying list itself.

You can also use an `ArrayAdapter` to customize the appearance of items in a `ListView` for example (or other Views) by using the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29) and passing in the `resource` of a layout to use, or by overriding the [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method and building it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, an adapter is some kind of translator. It's the "man in the middle" who know how to dialog with both sides and convert what is said.

An arrayAdapter is a class which get datas from an array and format it for a listview or spinner to understand it. When a listview need the data 4, for example, it will ask the adapter who will return him the 4 element of the array.

Ok, the listview could directly use the array.But with the adapter you're allowed to use any kind of data source. An ArrayAdapter(subclass of adapter) uses an Array, but another adapter could use a database or a file or anything else.That way the listview is able to get datas directly from any source without knowing how to access it.That is the adapter's role.